# tinymce text alignment issue

Tags: html, json, tinymce

I write text description in tinymce with spaces and html(line break and others etc etc).then i save it to mysql database.when i get it again and alert it,it shows me as same as it was.so till now it is fine.
When again i add it to tinymce to edit it,all html and spaces disappears..what can be the issue?
Here is my code

```
 $('#description').tinymce({
                // Location of TinyMCE script
                script_url : 'tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
                // General options
                width : "825",
                height: "300",
                theme : "advanced",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,bullist,numlist,spellchecker",
                theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
                theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
                theme_advanced_buttons4 : "",
                force_br_newlines : true,
                force_p_newlines : false,
                gecko_spellcheck : true,  
                forced_root_block : '', // Needed for 3.x

                plugins : "paste,spellchecker",
                spellchecker_languages : "+English=en,Russian=ru",
                // encoding : "xml",
                // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
                content_css : "tinymce/examples/css/content.css",

                //
                apply_source_formatting : true,

                // Replace values for the template plugin
                template_replace_values : {
                    username : "Some User",
                    staffid : "991234"
                }   
            });
```

here is how i am getting value

```
alert(json.description_demo);//this is ok
 $("#description").val(json.description_demo);
 alert($("#description").val());//now this is not ok..here is issue
```

tried this also

```
alert(json.description_demo);//ok
tinyMCE.get('description').setContent(json.description_demo);
alert(tinyMCE.get('description').getContent());//issue not ok
```

images
[image: working]
[image: notworking]
[image: after value]

Comment: How are you fetching and populating content from tinymce, write that also

Comment: i added al the last of question,please read again

Comment: what do you mean by "all html and spaces are gone"? can you show us an image or live example?

Comment: when i get from db,i get first alert..and when i assign to tinymcs i get last two..

Answer (score 0):

You must use `tinyMce` features to get and set the value. Try using:

```
tinyMCE.get('description').getContent(); // To get the value
```

```
tinyMCE.get('description').setContent(value from db); // To set the value
```

[Checkout tinymce docs](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent)

Comment: Check the value in variable, it should be inside <p> with formatting.

Comment: Try typing some text in editor and then alert the getContent method

Comment: when i write i editor,it is ok.issue is when i assign to it from database,as i mentioned in my question